# Disable initial resizing animation for NSScrollView containing NSOutlineView with dynamic row heights

Tags: cocoa, nsoutlineview, nsscrollview

I have an NSScrollview, containing an NSOutlineView (NSTableView should be relevant too) with automatic row heights enabled. Each row contains an NSTextField, which can be multiline, depending on column width and the length of its text. At the setup of the NSOutlineView, I want to show a selected row by highlighting it and scrolling to make it visible.

Autolayout works correctly, however, (as mentioned in https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKit/#10_13NSTableView%20Automatic%20Row%20Heights ) initial height of the outline view is determined by the static height value, or the delegate heightOfRow method. So that, the outline view estimates its preferred size twice in a short period with different values: first from heights and second from autolayout. (I've tried to make the delegate return the same height value as the autolayout, but without any success.)

However, despite the correct size is determined quickly (as there are no visible signs of row resizing), the NSScrollView seems to animate this size change for a few seconds, what can be seen as a visible shrinking of the vertical scroller. Moreover, this animation interferes with the scrolling to a selected row, which results in a jumpy scroller animation and, sometimes, to a wrong final position (with the selected row being outside of the visible area).

So, is there any way to (temporarily) disable the resize scrolling animation, or, maybe, any other method to solve this problem?